# Distributing data pipeline on SLURM PyTorch

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, computer-vision, slurm

I have a computer vision data pipeline that is time-consuming. It reads videos from a dataset of 400 GB. Currently, for each video, it takes 30 seconds. I am using PyTorch DataLoader for retrieving datasets.

While testing with `features, labels = next(iter(loader))`, I have experimented with different parameters.Like `loader = DataLoader(ds, num_workers=10, batch_size=3, collate_fn=my_collate)`, I tried changing num_workers from 0 to 10. It only works at 0. Takes much memory and space for `num_workers >= 2`. Doesn't even return any sequence for too long.
Following are some metrics I have captured:

#### Number of Workers: 0

Size of One Video (after preprocessing retrieved using sys.getsizeof): **67.7 MB**

Time for One video: **29.5 seconds**

Size of two videos: **130.9 MB**

Size of five videos: **334.17 MB**

Size of 10 videos: **663.17 MB**

Time for 10 videos: **4min 27s**

Max RAM usage during the process: **56 GB**

#### Number of Workers: 2

Max Memory usage: **110 GB**

It doesn't return any features/labels for multiple workers takes too long.

I am on **slurm** cluster and have 600 GBs of RAM and 40 CPU cores. But when I increase the num_workers, the RAM usage is increased but it doesn't return any results for too long.

My questions are:

- Is there any way I can optimize this computer vision pipeline?
- Can I use multiple CPU Cores and multiple slurm nodes for increasing speed? I have done research. The solutions available on the official torch portal don't solve the problem. I saw DistributedDataParallelCPU somewhere but it is not available in the documentation, etc.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using whole video? Or maybe you load whole video and take a random part of it? If second option, then split your videos into smaller chunks x5 - x20 times (with some overlapping maybe).

Comment: I have to use the whole video. Divide it into continuous sequences and feed it to the model.